# How to convert a hexadecimal character array into string in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, hex, type-conversion

So I have this data packet that I want to send it to my device using TCP/IP protocol. My array is:

```
unsigned char array1[] = {'0x00', '0x84', '0x00', '0x00', '0x00', '0x06', '0x54', '0x01', '0x00', '0x01', '0x00', '0x03'};
```

I want this to convert into a string. How do I do it?

Right now I am just manually writing down the decimal equivalent:

```
unsigned char array1[] = {0,132,0,0,0,6,84,5,0,2,255,0};
```

and converting it into string:

```
std::string data ( array1, array1 + sizeof array1 / sizeof array1[0] );
```

However, I wonder can I use my hex packet just like a string directly?

```
string x= "00 84 00 00 00 06 54 05 00 02 FF 00";
```

Also is there a way I can design my message header which is the first 7 bytes that dont change? What changes is the rest of the part?

Comment: Note that `'0x00'` is not really a single "character", it's a multi-byte character literal. Perhaps you mean e.g. `unsigned char array1[] = {0x00, 0x84, ... };`? *Without* the quotes?

Comment: Without the quotes, it throws warning for unsigned type.

Comment: Why exactly do you want it as `std::string`? I am not quite sure that this is the "correct" data type...

Comment: Because my class that I am inheriting, has the function to send this packet over the tcp network. The function only supports string. hence I need to convert my data into string.

Comment: @ArunavaNag The question is much clearer now!

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do what you need.

```
std::string s { "\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04", 5 };
```

Use the std::string constructor that also takes the length aka number of bytes.